# generate sandcastle documentation for c# solution

Tags: c#, documentation, documentation-generation, sandcastle

I have a vs2012 solution that has a number of C# projects. I would like to generate some documentation using Sandcastle for the entire library.

I have been reviewing Sandcastle documentation and not clear how I could generate the documentation for entire project.

How could I achieve this for the entire solution?

Comment: You can add an entire solution to SandCastle. Haven't you installed the tool you are reviewing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ChrisW indicated, you should use Sandcastle Help File Builder (SHFB). However, even with the clean and simple GUI provided by SHFB, however, there are quite a number of issues that you may need or want to consider in order to produce a tidy, professional documentation set. My article ("[Taming Sandcastle: A .NET Programmer's Guide to Documenting Your Code](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/taming-sandcastle-a-.net-programmers-guide-to-documenting-your-code/)") documenting my experience with a variety of potential pitfalls, published on Simple-Talk.com, may save you some time, effort, and agony :-).

Once you have digested the article, and perhaps of more interest, I put a complete syntax and usage guide to SHFB and Sandcastle on this [one-page wallchart](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/entrypage/code-profiling-made-easy-sandcastlechart?utm_source=simpletalk&utm_medium=email-reflector&utm_content=sandcastlechart&utm_campaign=antsperformanceprofiler), available on Simple-Talk.com. Here's a glimpse:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I used [Sandcastle Helpfile Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/) (instead of using Sandcastle directly).

In a SHFB project, you can specify multiple DLLs+XMLs in the `<DocumentationSources>` section.